# Scala: Copying a generic case class into another

Tags: scala, generics, shapeless

I have the following setup, where I want to copy an instance of `baseData` into that of `moreData`:

```
sealed trait baseData {
  def weight: Int
  def priority: Int
} 

sealed trait moreData {
  def weight: Int
  def priority: Int
  def t: String
  def id: String
} 

case class data1(override val weight: Int, override val priority: Int) extends baseData 
case class moreData1 (override val weight:Int, override val priority: Int, override val t: String, override val id: String)extends moreData
```

So copying `myData` into `otherData` below:

```
val myData = data1(1,1) 
val otherData = moreData1 (2,2,"C","abcd")
```

would yield: `moreData1(1,1,"C","abcd")`.

To do this, I want to use a function with the following signature, because I will have more than one case class extending both `baseData` and `moreData`:

```
def copyOver[A <:baseData, B <:moreData](from: A, to: B) = {}
```

I'm sure you can do this with [Shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0), but haven't figured out how. There are examples ([here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/basecopy.scala)) on copying case classes extending a same trait, and others ([here](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#generic-representation-of-sealed-families-of-case-classes)) mapping values between different case classes via generic representation. But I haven't figured out how to use `LabelledGeneric` with the trait-bounded arguments passed into `copyOver`. I also don't want to have to hardcode the extra fields in `otherData` that aren't present in `myData`.

I'm looking for a completely generic implementation. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the `UpdateRepr` type class from [your first shapeless example](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/shapeless/examples/basecopy.scala).

You could define `copyOver` using `UpdateRepr` as follows :

```
import shapeless._

// baseData, moreData, data1, moreData1
// UpdateRepr ...

def copyOver[A <: baseData, B <: moreData, R <: HList](
  from: A,
  to: B
)(implicit 
  lgen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, R],
  update: UpdateRepr[B, R]
): B = update(to, lgen.to(from))
```

Which you could use as follows :

```
val myData = data1(1,1) 
val otherData = moreData1(2,2,"C","abcd") 

copyOver(myData, otherData)
// moreData1 = moreData1(1,1,C,abcd)
```

Note that it is possible you run into problems with SI-7046, because of the sealed trait (Coproduct) type class derivation for `UpdateRepr`, which you could notice in the REPL or when splitting `UpdateRepr` and the sealed traits over multiple files.

Comment: Thanks, super helpful! One last hurdle is that I'm getting the following compilation error: `could not find implicit value for parameter update: cmd23.UpdateRepr[cmd19.moreData1,R]
copyOver(myData, otherData)` when calling copyOver. Any idea why?

Comment: If you are trying on the REPL, try using `Ctrl + P` with the sealed traits, case classes and `UpdateRepr` in one go.

Comment: Ah, yes it works when copying all in one go in paste mode. Thanks! 
Last question: if I understand `UpdateRepr` correctly, `baseData` has to be an exact subset of `moreData` for this to work. Meaning `baseData` cannot have any field not present in `moreData`. Would you agree?